# Searching in an array using v-model in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to create a searching component using Vue 3 to allow a user to insert text and have it display all available results. I am basing my code off this example: https://codepen.io/thaekeh/pen/PoGJRKQ

However, it does not seem to want to work, as I am sure it has something to do with v-model for the search bar. The search bar also seems to be floating and wont stay in one place, so if anyone has a fix for that also that would be great.

This is my code thus far (excuse the missing pictures):

```js
//############--search.js--############

//--------------- PAGE TITLE ---------------
// Vue object: Title
const PageTitle = {
    data() {
        return {
            title: 'Search'
        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(PageTitle).mount('#page-title')

//--------------- FOOTER ---------------//
// Vue object: Footer text
const FooterText = {
    data() {
        return {
            footer_text: 'Created by ##'
        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(FooterText).mount('#footer-text')

//--------------- NAVIGATION (Cart) ---------------//
// Vue object: Title
const CartTitle = {
    data() {
        return {
            cart_title: 'Cart'
        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(CartTitle).mount('#cart-title')

//--------------- NAVIGATION (Main pages) ---------------//
// Vue object: Title
const MainNav = {
    data() {
        return {
            home: 'Home',
            for_hire: 'For Hire',
            about: 'About',
            contact_us: 'Contact Us',
            search: 'Search'
        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(MainNav).mount('#nav-titles')


//--------------- SEARCH FUNCTION ---------------//
// Custom Vue Component: Binding information to each hiring container
const searchChoiceBox = {
    name: 'search-choice-box',
    props: ['name', 'image', 'price', 'rating'],
    template: `
      <div class = "option_container">
          <img class = "option_image" :src="image">
          <i class="fa fa-cart-plus fa-4x" id = "add_cart"></i>
          <h4 class = "option_name">{{name}}</h4>
          <h4 class = "option_price">{{price}}</h4>
          <img class = "rating" :src="rating">
      </div>
      `
};

// Vue object: Available options to search
const SearchData = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        searchValue: '',
        options: [{
            name: 'Akira Tozawa',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_13.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$30/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Bobby Lashley',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_1.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$200/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Brock Lesnar',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_2.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$300/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Commander Azeez',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_3.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/2_stars.png",
            list_price: "$40/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Corey Grimes',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_14.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/2_stars.png",
            list_price: "$20/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Drew McIntyre',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_4.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$100/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Gran Metalik',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_5.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$60/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Jeff Hardy',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_6.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$120/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Jinder Mahal',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_15.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$50/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'John Cena',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_7.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$900/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Kevin Owens',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_8.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$85/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Lince Derado',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_9.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$60/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Pete Dunne',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_10.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$70/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Sheamus',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_11.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$80/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'T-Bone',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_16.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$30/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Undertaker',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_12.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$400/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Table',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/table.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$50/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Steel Chair',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/steel_chair.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$30/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Ladder',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/ladder.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$100/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Guitar',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/guitar.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$40/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Thumbtacks',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/thumbtacks.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/2_stars.png",
            list_price: "$15/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Kendo stick',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/kendo_stick.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$30/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Sledgehammer',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/sledge_hammer.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$45/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Crutch',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/crutch.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/2_stars.png",
            list_price: "$25/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Wrestling ring',
            image_src: "../Assets/Rings/wrestling_ring.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$400/ring"
          },
          {
            name: 'MMA ring',
            image_src: "../Assets/Rings/mma_ring.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$500/ring"
          },
          {
            name: 'Wrestling mat',
            image_src: "../Assets/Rings/wrestling_mat.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$50/mat"
          },
          {
            name: 'Trampoline',
            image_src: "../Assets/Rings/trampoline.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/2_stars.png",
            list_price: "$400/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'DIY ring',
            image_src: "../Assets/Rings/diy_ring.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/2_stars.png",
            list_price: "$30/ring"
          },
          {
            name: 'TLC match',
            image_src: "../Assets/Match type/tlc_match.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$300"
          },
          {
            name: 'Hell in a cell',
            image_src: "../Assets/Match type/hell_in_cell.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$1000"
          },
          {
            name: 'Extreme rules',
            image_src: "../Assets/Match type/extreme_rules.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$500"
          },
          {
            name: 'Backstage brawl',
            image_src: "../Assets/Match type/backstage_brawl.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$150"
          },
          {
            name: 'TLC match',
            image_src: "../Assets/Match type/royal_rumble.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$400"},
        ]};
    },

    computed: {
        searchResult() {
        let tempHire = this.options
        
        if (this.searchValue != '' && this.searchValue) {
            tempHire = tempHire.filter((item) => {
                return item.name
                  .toUpperCase()
                  .includes(this.searchValue.toUpperCase())
              })
            }
          return tempHire
        }
    }
});

SearchData.component('search-choice-box', searchChoiceBox);
SearchData.mount('#search-data');
```

```css
/* Stylesheet for SIT120 Project - search.css */
/*----------------------------------------------------*/

/*/////////////////////////-NO margins-//////////////////////////////*/
/* Expands to width of screen*/
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*/////////////////////////-Header Navigation-//////////////////////////////*/

/* Top navigation (cart) */
.cart_nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #C6393F; 
}

.cart_nav li {
    float: right;
}

.cart_nav li a {
    font-family: Actor;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding: 15px 55px 15px 20px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    
}

.cart_nav li a:hover 
{
    color:#AAAAAA;
}

/*/////////////////////////-Cart Number-//////////////////////////////*/

/* Cart number (circled) */
.cart_items 
{
    font-family: Righteous;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color:#2C2C2C;
    float: right; 
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-left: -33px;
    border-radius: 60%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 22px;
    text-align: center; 
}

/*/////////////////////////-Cart icons-//////////////////////////////*/

/* Top navigation ICONS (cart) */
.cart_icon
{
    display:inline-flex;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    margin-right: -17px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

/*/////////////////////////-Main navigation-//////////////////////////////*/

/* Main navigation (pages) */
.page_nav ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
}

.page_nav li 
{
    float: left;
}

.page_nav li a {
    font-family: Bai Jamjuree;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #AAAAAA;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 40px 60px 35px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.07em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.page_nav li a:hover 
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

.page_nav li a.active
{
    text-decoration: overline;
    color:#FFFFFF;

}
.page_nav li a:focus
{
    text-decoration: overline;
    color:#FFFFFF;

}

/*/////////////////////////-Navigation sub-menus-//////////////////////////////*/


/*/////////////////////////-Navigation icon (Search)-//////////////////////////////*/

/* Main navigation search ICON */
.search_icon
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 37px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    margin-right: -50px;
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-right: 45px;
}

/*/////////////////////////-LOGO-//////////////////////////////*/

 /* Main logo (Wrestle Hire logo) */
.site_logo
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 145px; 
    padding-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

.site_logo:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
}



/*/////////////////////////-FOOTER-//////////////////////////////*/

.footer_component{ 
  border-top: solid #C6393F;
  border-width: 15px;
  background: #2C2C2C; 
  position: absolute; 
  height:100%;
  width:100%; 
  height: 130px;
  ;

}

.text_footer {
  color: #424242;
  font-family: Actor;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

/*/////////////////////////-SEARCH BAR-//////////////////////////////*/
.search_wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #807d7d;
    max-width: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: -100px;
}

.search-bar
{
    width: 80%;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Bai Jamjuree;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #2d2d2d;
}

::placeholder {
    font-family: Abel;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: rgb(181, 179, 179);
}

.search_button
{
    background: #C6393F;
    width:10%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.search_button .fa
{
    position: relative;
    top: -10%;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%);
    font-size: 30px;
}

/*/////////////////////////-Hiring selection - Wrestlers-//////////////////////////////*/

/* Selection layout */
.option_row
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 10em;
}

.option_container
{
    flex-basis: 20%;
    padding: 17px;
    min-width: 200px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.option_container:hover
{
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #C6393F;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.option_list_container
{
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

/* Hiring selection information */
.option_list_container h2
{
    font-family: Rajdhani;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: #2C2C2C;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 45px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #555;

}

.option_list_container h2::after
{
    content: '';
    background: #ff523b;
    width: 80px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 44%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.option_name
{
    font-family: Bai Jamjuree;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.option_image
{
    width: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.rating
{
    max-width: 75px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: -2em;
}

.option_price
{
    font-family: Bai Jamjuree;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}

#add_cart
{
    color: black;
    float: right;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#add_cart:hover
{
    color: #C6393F;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML FILE: search.html-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Stylesheets-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="search.css">

        <!--Link Vue Framework-->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

        <!-- Set responsiveness to screen size -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    

        <!--Google fonts-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bai Jamjuree">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel">
        
        <!--Search icon (Font Awesome)-->
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d83f9b7e69.js"></script>

        <!--Page Icon-->
        <link rel="icon" href="../Assets/page_icon.png">

        <!-- Page title-->
        <title id="page-title">{{title}}</title>
    </head>
    
    <body id = "hire-now-button">
        <!--NAVIGATION-->
        <header>
            <!--Top navigation section (login, account and cart)-->
            <div class = "cart_nav" id = "cart-title">
                <ul>
                    <div class = "cart_items">0</div>
                    <li><a href="#cart">{{cart_title}}<img class = "cart_icon" src="../Assets/cart.png" alt="cart_icon"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

              <!--Main navigation section (main pages)-->
            <div class = "page_nav" id = "nav-titles">
                <ul>
                    <!--All main pages will have .html files, this example has the contact as a separate file (and empty files)-->
                    <a href="../Home/home.html"><img href ="../Home/home.html" class = "site_logo" id = "siteLogo" src="../Assets/website_logo.png"/></a>
                    <li><a class = "active" href="../Home/home.html">{{home}}</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Hiring Selection/hiring_selection.html">{{for_hire}}</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">{{about}}</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Contact/contact.html">{{contact_us}}</a></li>
                    <li class = "search" style="float:right"><a href = "">{{search}}<img class = "search_icon" src="../Assets/search.png" alt="search_icon"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>

        <!--Body for search bar and options-->
        <div id="search-data">
            <!--Search bar to find all hiring options on the site-->
            <div class="search_wrapper">
                <input type="text" class ="search-bar" v-model = "searchValue" placeholder="Search hiring options of Wrestle Hire">
                <div class = "search_button">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!--All hiring options available-->
            <div class = "option_list_container">
                <div class = "option_row">
                    <search-choice-box v-for="hire in options" 
                    :name="hire.name" :image="hire.image_src" 
                    :rating="hire.star_ratings":price = "hire.list_price">
                    </search-choice-box>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Footer of page-->
        <footer id = "footer-text">
            <div class="footer_component">
                <div class = "text_footer" >
                    <h2 >{{footer_text}}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        
    </body>

    
    <!-- Link JavaScript file -->
    <script src="search.js"></script>

</html>
```

I am using a computed property to filter out the search, however I am unsure if that even works either. Any advice would be great, and please answer by changing up the code as I am very new to Vue 3, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem was found in

```
`<search-choice-box v-for="hire in options" :name="hire.name" :image="hire.image_src" :rating="hire.star_ratings":price = "hire.list_price"> </search-choice-box>`
```

. Why? because the options is a data and you want is the result of the computed searchResult. So, you can call in v-for to this. You can use this code

```
`<search-choice-box v-for="hire in searchResult" :name="hire.name" :image="hire.image_src" :rating="hire.star_ratings":price = "hire.list_price"> </search-choice-box>`
```

```
//############--search.js--############

//--------------- PAGE TITLE ---------------
// Vue object: Title
const PageTitle = {
    data() {
        return {
            title: 'Search'
        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(PageTitle).mount('#page-title')

//--------------- FOOTER ---------------//
// Vue object: Footer text
const FooterText = {
    data() {
        return {
            footer_text: 'Created by ##'
        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(FooterText).mount('#footer-text')

//--------------- NAVIGATION (Cart) ---------------//
// Vue object: Title
const CartTitle = {
    data() {
        return {
            cart_title: 'Cart'
        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(CartTitle).mount('#cart-title')

//--------------- NAVIGATION (Main pages) ---------------//
// Vue object: Title
const MainNav = {
    data() {
        return {
            home: 'Home',
            for_hire: 'For Hire',
            about: 'About',
            contact_us: 'Contact Us',
            search: 'Search'
        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(MainNav).mount('#nav-titles')


//--------------- SEARCH FUNCTION ---------------//
// Custom Vue Component: Binding information to each hiring container
const searchChoiceBox = {
    name: 'search-choice-box',
    props: ['name', 'image', 'price', 'rating'],
    template: `
      <div class = "option_container">
          <img class = "option_image" :src="image">
          <i class="fa fa-cart-plus fa-4x" id = "add_cart"></i>
          <h4 class = "option_name">{{name}}</h4>
          <h4 class = "option_price">{{price}}</h4>
          <img class = "rating" :src="rating">
      </div>
      `
};

// Vue object: Available options to search
const SearchData = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        searchValue: '',
        options: [{
            name: 'Akira Tozawa',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_13.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$30/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Bobby Lashley',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_1.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$200/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Brock Lesnar',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_2.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$300/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Commander Azeez',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_3.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/2_stars.png",
            list_price: "$40/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Corey Grimes',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_14.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/2_stars.png",
            list_price: "$20/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Drew McIntyre',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_4.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$100/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Gran Metalik',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_5.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$60/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Jeff Hardy',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_6.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$120/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Jinder Mahal',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_15.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$50/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'John Cena',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_7.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$900/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Kevin Owens',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_8.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$85/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Lince Derado',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_9.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$60/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Pete Dunne',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_10.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$70/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Sheamus',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_11.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$80/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'T-Bone',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_16.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$30/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Undertaker',
            image_src: "../Assets/Wrestlers/wrestler_12.png",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$400/hour"
          },
          {
            name: 'Table',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/table.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$50/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Steel Chair',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/steel_chair.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$30/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Ladder',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/ladder.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$100/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Guitar',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/guitar.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$40/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Thumbtacks',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/thumbtacks.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/2_stars.png",
            list_price: "$15/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Kendo stick',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/kendo_stick.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$30/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Sledgehammer',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/sledge_hammer.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$45/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Crutch',
            image_src: "../Assets/Items/crutch.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/2_stars.png",
            list_price: "$25/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'Wrestling ring',
            image_src: "../Assets/Rings/wrestling_ring.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$400/ring"
          },
          {
            name: 'MMA ring',
            image_src: "../Assets/Rings/mma_ring.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$500/ring"
          },
          {
            name: 'Wrestling mat',
            image_src: "../Assets/Rings/wrestling_mat.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$50/mat"
          },
          {
            name: 'Trampoline',
            image_src: "../Assets/Rings/trampoline.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/2_stars.png",
            list_price: "$400/item"
          },
          {
            name: 'DIY ring',
            image_src: "../Assets/Rings/diy_ring.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/2_stars.png",
            list_price: "$30/ring"
          },
          {
            name: 'TLC match',
            image_src: "../Assets/Match type/tlc_match.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$300"
          },
          {
            name: 'Hell in a cell',
            image_src: "../Assets/Match type/hell_in_cell.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/5_stars.png",
            list_price: "$1000"
          },
          {
            name: 'Extreme rules',
            image_src: "../Assets/Match type/extreme_rules.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$500"
          },
          {
            name: 'Backstage brawl',
            image_src: "../Assets/Match type/backstage_brawl.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/3_stars.png",
            list_price: "$150"
          },
          {
            name: 'TLC match',
            image_src: "../Assets/Match type/royal_rumble.jpg",
            star_ratings: "../Assets/Ratings/4_stars.png",
            list_price: "$400"},
        ]};
    },

    computed: {
        searchResult() {
        let tempHire = this.options
        
        if (this.searchValue != '' && this.searchValue) {
            tempHire = tempHire.filter((item) => {
                return item.name
                  .toUpperCase()
                  .includes(this.searchValue.toUpperCase())
              })
            }
          return tempHire
        }
    }
});

SearchData.component('search-choice-box', searchChoiceBox);
SearchData.mount('#search-data');
```

```
/* Stylesheet for SIT120 Project - search.css */
/*----------------------------------------------------*/

/*/////////////////////////-NO margins-//////////////////////////////*/
/* Expands to width of screen*/
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*/////////////////////////-Header Navigation-//////////////////////////////*/

/* Top navigation (cart) */
.cart_nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #C6393F; 
}

.cart_nav li {
    float: right;
}

.cart_nav li a {
    font-family: Actor;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding: 15px 55px 15px 20px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    
}

.cart_nav li a:hover 
{
    color:#AAAAAA;
}

/*/////////////////////////-Cart Number-//////////////////////////////*/

/* Cart number (circled) */
.cart_items 
{
    font-family: Righteous;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color:#2C2C2C;
    float: right; 
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-left: -33px;
    border-radius: 60%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 22px;
    text-align: center; 
}

/*/////////////////////////-Cart icons-//////////////////////////////*/

/* Top navigation ICONS (cart) */
.cart_icon
{
    display:inline-flex;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    margin-right: -17px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

/*/////////////////////////-Main navigation-//////////////////////////////*/

/* Main navigation (pages) */
.page_nav ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
}

.page_nav li 
{
    float: left;
}

.page_nav li a {
    font-family: Bai Jamjuree;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #AAAAAA;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 40px 60px 35px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.07em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.page_nav li a:hover 
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

.page_nav li a.active
{
    text-decoration: overline;
    color:#FFFFFF;

}
.page_nav li a:focus
{
    text-decoration: overline;
    color:#FFFFFF;

}

/*/////////////////////////-Navigation sub-menus-//////////////////////////////*/


/*/////////////////////////-Navigation icon (Search)-//////////////////////////////*/

/* Main navigation search ICON */
.search_icon
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 37px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    margin-right: -50px;
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-right: 45px;
}

/*/////////////////////////-LOGO-//////////////////////////////*/

  /* Main logo (Wrestle Hire logo) */
.site_logo
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 145px; 
    padding-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

.site_logo:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
}



/*/////////////////////////-FOOTER-//////////////////////////////*/

.footer_component{ 
  border-top: solid #C6393F;
  border-width: 15px;
  background: #2C2C2C; 
  position: absolute; 
  height:100%;
  width:100%; 
  height: 130px;
  ;

}

.text_footer {
  color: #424242;
  font-family: Actor;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

/*/////////////////////////-SEARCH BAR-//////////////////////////////*/
.search_wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #807d7d;
    max-width: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: -100px;
}

.search-bar
{
    width: 80%;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Bai Jamjuree;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #2d2d2d;
}

::placeholder {
    font-family: Abel;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: rgb(181, 179, 179);
}

.search_button
{
    background: #C6393F;
    width:10%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.search_button .fa
{
    position: relative;
    top: -10%;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%);
    font-size: 30px;
}

/*/////////////////////////-Hiring selection - Wrestlers-//////////////////////////////*/

/* Selection layout */
.option_row
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 10em;
}

.option_container
{
    flex-basis: 20%;
    padding: 17px;
    min-width: 200px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.option_container:hover
{
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #C6393F;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.option_list_container
{
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

/* Hiring selection information */
.option_list_container h2
{
    font-family: Rajdhani;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: #2C2C2C;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 45px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #555;

}

.option_list_container h2::after
{
    content: '';
    background: #ff523b;
    width: 80px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 44%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.option_name
{
    font-family: Bai Jamjuree;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.option_image
{
    width: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.rating
{
    max-width: 75px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: -2em;
}

.option_price
{
    font-family: Bai Jamjuree;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}

#add_cart
{
    color: black;
    float: right;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#add_cart:hover
{
    color: #C6393F;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```
<!--HTML FILE: search.html-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Stylesheets-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="search.css">

        <!--Link Vue Framework-->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

        <!-- Set responsiveness to screen size -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    

        <!--Google fonts-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bai Jamjuree">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel">
        
        <!--Search icon (Font Awesome)-->
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d83f9b7e69.js"></script>

        <!--Page Icon-->
        <link rel="icon" href="../Assets/page_icon.png">

        <!-- Page title-->
        <title id="page-title">{{title}}</title>
    </head>
    
    <body id = "hire-now-button">
        <!--NAVIGATION-->
        <header>
            <!--Top navigation section (login, account and cart)-->
            <div class = "cart_nav" id = "cart-title">
                <ul>
                    <div class = "cart_items">0</div>
                    <li><a href="#cart">{{cart_title}}<img class = "cart_icon" src="../Assets/cart.png" alt="cart_icon"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

              <!--Main navigation section (main pages)-->
            <div class = "page_nav" id = "nav-titles">
                <ul>
                    <!--All main pages will have .html files, this example has the contact as a separate file (and empty files)-->
                    <a href="../Home/home.html"><img href ="../Home/home.html" class = "site_logo" id = "siteLogo" src="../Assets/website_logo.png"/></a>
                    <li><a class = "active" href="../Home/home.html">{{home}}</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Hiring Selection/hiring_selection.html">{{for_hire}}</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">{{about}}</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Contact/contact.html">{{contact_us}}</a></li>
                    <li class = "search" style="float:right"><a href = "">{{search}}<img class = "search_icon" src="../Assets/search.png" alt="search_icon"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>

        <!--Body for search bar and options-->
        <div id="search-data">
            <!--Search bar to find all hiring options on the site-->
            <div class="search_wrapper">
                <input type="text" class ="search-bar" v-model = "searchValue" placeholder="Search hiring options of Wrestle Hire">
                <div class = "search_button">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!--All hiring options available-->
            <div class = "option_list_container">
                <div class = "option_row">
                    <search-choice-box v-for="hire in searchResult" 
                    :name="hire.name" :image="hire.image_src" 
                    :rating="hire.star_ratings":price = "hire.list_price">
                    </search-choice-box>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Footer of page-->
        <footer id = "footer-text">
            <div class="footer_component">
                <div class = "text_footer" >
                    <h2 >{{footer_text}}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        
    </body>

    
    <!-- Link JavaScript file -->
    <script src="search.js"></script>

</html>
```